# Subscription in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hook

Ребята, подскажите как происходит механизм подписки в Реакт, не совсем понятно, в subscribeToFriendsStatus вторым аргументом попадает результат выполнения функции handleStatusChange или как?

```
class FriendStatus extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { isOnline: null };
this.handleStatusChange = this.handleStatusChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(
  this.props.friend.id,
  this.handleStatusChange
);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(
  this.props.friend.id,
  this.handleStatusChange
);
}

 handleStatusChange(status) {
this.setState({
  isOnline: status.isOnline
});
}

render() {
 if (this.state.isOnline === null) {
  return 'Загрузка...';
 }
 return this.state.isOnline ? 'В сети' : 'Не в сети';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, что этот код был взят из объяснения команды `Facebook` работы [хуков](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

В данном примере ребята хотели показать 2 примера реализации одного и того же функционала(в данном случае некое абстрактная реализация `API`): в классическом примере(с помощью `componentDidMount` и `componentDidUnmount`) и новом(с помощью `useEffect`).

Функции `ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus` и `ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus` - используются для того, чтобы объяснить принцип работы нововведений(таких как `useEffect`, например), поэтому в самом реакте такого функционала нет.

Что касается твоего второго вопроса: 2 аргументом попадает функция.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Возможно не так вопрос поставила. Вопрос более касался самой функции подписки, Я так понимаю, что тут реализован паттерн Observer и мы добавляем таким образом функцию в массив подписчиков?

Comment: @AnnaSwan Нет, скорее всего где-то внутри реализации `ChatApi` хранится массив подписчиков с их текущими статусами. С помощью методов `subscribeToFriendStatus` и `unsubscribeFromFriendStatus ` происходит подписка и отписка, соответственно. Обновление данных пользователей происходит, вероятно, с помощью еще какого-то метода(таймер это или websocket-ы, например, не особо важно). В момент обновления вызывается переданная функция `handleStatusChange`, которая обновляет стейт компонента, что приводит к его перерендерингу.